# How to pass parameter from AngularJS $http.post to ASP .NET Web API core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, angular-http

I want to call ASP .NET Web API from the Angular web page.
I have written the following API:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string user)
{
   return Json(new RequestResult
   {
     State = RequestState.Success,
     Msg = "Welcome"
   });
}
```

And calling above using in Angular as:

```
$http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:50087/api/tokenauth/login',
        data: 'm2pathan',
        headers: {
                   'Content-type': 'application/json, charset=UTF-8'
                 }
     }) 
   .then(function loginSuccessCallback(response) {
   console.log("In loginSuccessCallback", response);
```

But I am getting 'Null' value in 'user' variable of API.
Please help me.

Image:Error showing after adding [FromBody] in parameter of API.
[image]

Comment: because content-type of you is json and data you send not json file

Comment: I have also tried using JSON format as `data: { "user" : "m2pathan" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).
I have added the policy in my startup.cs in ConfigureServices() method as bellow:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});
```

and added it before the action as:

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TokenAuthController : Controller
{
    //my action methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Actually you have passing only one parameter and return the data to response. So the better way to use `GET` method instead of `POST` method with pass the parameter via `QueryString`

---

- But If you want POST method only, then you could go to this below way

  ```
  var body = JSON.stringify({ user: 'm2pathan'});
  $http.post('http://localhost:50087/api/tokenauth/login', body)
  .then(function loginSuccessCallback(response) {
  console.log("In loginSuccessCallback", response);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ramesh answer, you should use `[FromBody]` attribute (see [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)) if you need to populate user from request body:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] string user)
```

Comment: After adding `[FromBody]` in the parameter, I am getting error "Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type"

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

First you set `Content-Type` to `application/json`, but then you send invalid JSON. Use `JSON.stringify({user: 'm2pathan'}` to build a valid JSON.

Then in your ASP.NET Core application you need to use a complex type instead of simple type `string` in your action `Login`. Most likely you will need to send password and other parameters anyway so add the class like this:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

and then change your `Login` action to

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginRequest request)
{
    return Json(new RequestResult
    {
        State = RequestState.Success,
        Msg = "Welcome"
    });
}
```

Now you should be OK.

Comment: After adding `[FromBody]` in the parameter, I am getting error "Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Try to use semicolon instead of comma to separate values in Content-Type string `application/json, charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Chrome/Firefox developer tools too see what exact headers go to server and back?

Comment: Sure, Please check

Comment: It looks like you are sending requests to a cross-origin resource which might be a root cause of the problem here. I'm not really an expert here so not sure I can help you with that. The approach I proposed is working on my local environment where both client and api are hosted on the same origin.

Comment: Now, I have also tried to host api on the same server of client(localhost), but still getting same error.

Comment: By any chance can you share your code or upload a sample project to GitHub where you can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142756/discussion-between-alexey-andrushkevich-and-m2pathan).

Comment: Thanks Alexey! I have traced the problem. its related to CORS. I need to add policy to access it from the different port/URL.

Comment: You are welcome. Just want to note that your answer doesn't relate to your original question. Originally the issue was with sending correct JSON, setting up attribute [FromBody] and using complex type instead of simple type `string`. The issue with CORS was an additional factor why my answer didn't make your app working...